# Set size to CodeMirror editor?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, codemirror, sizing

I'm creating mobile app using jQuery Mobile and CodeMirror as a code editor.
I'm not a designer so I don't usually mess up with CSS.

This is what I have so far [image: Valid XHTML]
.

I want CodeMirror control to be stretched down to footer.
Css height property won't work here.

// Edit

Problem was in height of the parent DIV, sorry

Comment: btw.. `height: 100vh;` will work for you.. but it's make issues with the scroller of the editor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't write comments yet. did you try `editor.setSize(width, height)`